# Why questions without code get downvoted?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, downvote-reason

I've seen many question that included no code, because it wasn't about someone's not working code, it was just about someone asking how ....... can be done in ..... language or similar questions, and they are not asking for entire codes most of the time, yet these questions got downvoted really fast, even if it actually was a good one.

Why is that? Why do so many downvote questions that has no code in it?

Comment: "How can I do X" is usually WAY too broad. That's why most of the time people ask for code. When you ask "how do I do X", you're either starting working on the issue (too broad of a question for Stack), or you're already working on something, have some code and are blocked on a specific thing (ask about that specific thing instead).

Comment: This will vary widely based on the question and the voter... It's hard to answer this one generally. Though based on your description, I'd guess they came across as "Give me the code" questions, whether they were or not. Generally, if you're trying to find out how to do a thing in a language, you'll want to show what you've tried yourself, both to help narrow down what you already know and also to save some time for answerers.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ covers it pretty succinctly

Comment: Questions can be great without any code. We downvote, not because there’s no code, but because there’s no _research or attempt_ demonstrated, usually. The obvious answer to “How to do _X_ in language _Y_” is “By writing code”. So, if the question is only asking that, then clearly no attempt has been made, otherwise there would be code to be shown. Even if the asker truly couldn’t find how to even begin writing _X_, there would still be tons of research shown in the question.

Comment: @Patrice that's true, but there are other kind of questions that don't require any code to be included, and they are reasonable, yet get downvoted

Comment: You don't provide examples.. *most* programming questions require some code even if it's *just to demonstrate the issue or what research has been done*.

Comment: @K.P. do you have any examples of questions that get downvoted yet you think are reasonable?  Perhaps we could help you understand why they might have been downvoted.

Comment: If a question, for some reason, does not require code, it might still be inappropriate for SO and so get downvoted accordingly.

Comment: I have no problem, in general, with questions without actual code.  If a question asks about a narrow design issue, (and, of course, I have a clue:), then I am happy to try and answer it.  Such questions usually have more than one sentence/paragraph, and not just 'How do I do X in Y?'.  If it's a one-liner, or a requirement spec, then down it goes.

Comment: Also, http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch Your question may not have code, but it needs to show what you've attempted to do, what you've researched, and what happened. All this information prevents others from going over the same ground you've traveled.

Answer (score 9):

> I've seen many question that included no code, because it wasn't about someone's not working code, it was just about someone asking how ....... can be done in ..... language or similar questions

Usually "how can x be done in (eg. C#)" type questions with no code are one of the following:

- Homework style question dumps (here's a spec, write me a solution)
- Questions that are very broad ("How do I show a table in C#" - could be solved hundreds of different ways depending on the spec, what do you mean by table, etc.)
- Questions that show absolutely no research effort.

[It's certainly not the case that all these "How can I" questions get downvoted if they don't have code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-most-recent-commits-in-git)

Comment: I'm not convinced that question from 2009 would have survived today though, but other than that I agree. A question doesn't *need* code to be good but it certainly helps.

Comment: @ivarni on-topic no-research question can be extremely useful to a lot of people (like in the case of linked "undo last commit"). So the first one (or the main duplicate) will eventually collect upvotes, but the rest of duplicates will likely stay in negative. (Also I'm not really sure what berry120 meant by linking this question in the answer)

Answer (score 9):

First and foremost, **we can't read minds**, so it's impossible to know why individual voters voted the way they did. Votes are anonymous, and **only the voter knows why they voted one way or another**.

In a more general sense, without an specific example of a *"reasonable question that doesn't have code and still gets down-votes"* is very difficult to argue with your premise.

So far, I'm sorry but I believe is mostly false. Some good questions get down-voted, with or without code; but I do not think it is a generalized problem but freak instances.

Many questions lacking code may receive down-votes because they show no research, or they are too broad, or they are eminently unclear. Or all of the above.

This is a *programming* Q&A site. While there are a lot of good questions without code... most of the time good questions will require **some** code to be understandable and useful.